# How to make Windows 10 recognize an Apple Super Drive A1379?

Tags: windows

Have a new Lenovo Yoga PC with Windows 10. I want to continue using my external disk reader, an Apple Super Drive A1379.

How can I make them them communicate with each other? Right now, the disk reader refuses to take in any CDs. I am not computer savvy, need easiest route. Or simply to know if it cannot be done. Thank you.